# Dynamically remove search results

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am building a search feature in a web app. I have got it sort of working but can't figure out how to remove items as the user backspaces, the letters in the [search bar no longer match the items](https://ibb.co/KzZ6wKY) that have appeared or if the search term is emptied completely.

All the results just stay there.

Here is the AJAX call

```
$("#search-box").keyup(function() {
  search()
});

const search = function() {
  let searchTerm = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/electra/search/',
      data: {
        'search_term': searchTerm
      },
      success: function(data) {
        data.forEach(([cafeName]) => {
          var cafeName = cafeName;
          var searchList = $(
            `<div>
                    <ul class="list-item border-top" data-idtext="${cafeName}" id="${cafeName}">${cafeName}</ul>
                </div>`
          );
          searchList.appendTo('#search-results');
        });
  
        $("ul").click(function(event) {
          var selectedVenue = event.target.id;
          $("#search-results").empty()
          console.log("Clicked" + " " + selectedVenue);
          getVenueDetails(selectedVenue)
        });
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: You'll need to send the request again. ie: call `search()` again when the value changes

Comment: Note that `<ul>` is not a content element. Content needs to be in `<li>` within a `<ul>`

Comment: @CarlMarkham I updated the original OP with the event, it is triggered by keyups

Comment: You will also need to clear the results every time you search, otherwise you just add to the list. You're already doing `$("#search-results").empty()` when you click, do the same at the top of the `search` function

Comment: Fantastic thank you. The last part - when the search bar is empty it still returns some results (I think the most recently added to the database). Is there a way to check if empty and return nothing? Here is what I mean: https://ibb.co/1f9Qs52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When text is entered and you call `search` you are appending the results to the existing list

```
searchList.appendTo('#search-results')
```

You will need to empty the results when new text is added. You can simply call

```
$("#search-results").empty()
```

at the start of the `search` function.

A couple of notes:

- `var cafeName = cafeName;` is pointless and can be removed.
- In your `keyup` handler, you can check the length of the text. If it's blank, just remove the search results and don't bother calling `search`

```
$("#search-box").keyup(function() {
  const searchTerm = document.getElementById("search-box").value;

  if (searchTerm.length === 0) {
    $("#search-results").empty()
    return // don't need to do anything else
  }

  search()
})
```

- For performance, it's best to set a minimum length before you start searching. If the search box only contains the letter `a`, that's going to be a lot of pointless matches. Consider a minimum of 3 to return better matches.

```
$("#search-box").keyup(function() {
  const searchTerm = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
  
  // Don't want to search if only a few characters
  if (searchTerm.length < 3) {
    if (searchTerm.length === 0) {
      // Deleted search term so remove everything
      $("#search-results").empty()
    }
    return // don't need to do anything else
  }

  search()
})
```

- As mentioned in the comments, `ul` should contain an `li`. If you don't want this and each `ul` is clickable, make it an anchor element.

```
var searchList = $(
  `<div>
    <a href="#" class="list-item border-top" data-idtext="${cafeName}" id="${cafeName}">${cafeName}</a>
  </div>`
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help